# Typescript cannot load SVG as react components

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to import in Typescript some SVG icons, but I'm facing some problems.

At the first time I tried to import them, Typescript wasn't able to recognize the file extension.
I solved this issue by creating, as suggested in other Stack Overflow and Github topics, a `custom.d.ts` file with this rule inside:

```js
declare module "*.svg" {
  const content: React.StatelessComponent<React.SVGAttributes<SVGElement>>;
  export default content;
}
```

But the problems seem to not finish here, even if the compilation seems going fine.

The current project I'm working on, is structured this way:

- Typescript + React package (with SVG icons files) (SDK)
- React Internal Sample page (package) to use the SDK
- other internal packages...

For our development phase, we build through Webpack all the packages through different loaders and see the result through the Sample page.

But the final product flow to production is quite different: I export the SDK as CommonJS to an internal NPM Registry so another company can use it in a React project (the equivalent of the Sample page but for production) and push to production the final Webpack bundles with both projects inside.

So, to load in the Sample application the SVG icons, I'm using `@svgr/webpack` loader, which converts the files.

But when I have to export the SDK through `npx tsc`, I see that the exported folder, does not contain the folders with `svg` files.

I've tried to include them in `tsconfig.json/files`, but got this error:

```sh
TS6054: File '<path>/*.svg' has an unsupported extension. The only supported extensions are '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts'.
```

So, to attempt exporting them I converted my exporting script to use `@svgr/cli` to export the files to React files from SVGs before compiling to typescript:

```
// package.json
scripts: {
    "build-ts": "rm -rf ./lib; yarn convert-svg-to-react; npx tsc",
    "convert-svg-to-react": "npx @svgr/cli -d src src --typescript",
}
```

In this way, I get the new Typescript files mixed with the SVGs inside the package (so I'll have to remove them later) and I can see them in the exported folder `lib`.
But watching inside the Typescript exported code, I can see this line (for each svg import):

```js
var close_svg_1 = __importDefault(require("./icons/close.svg"));
```

Leaving out the Typescript function for Babel `__importDefault`, you can see that it still requires the file `svg`, but what I have at this point, are the React components that replaces those files.

During development it works fine because `@svgr/webpack` loader, resolves the `svg` files.
But requiring svg files that do not exist, should make the application above it crash.

So, I'm stuck and I need some clues to get out of this situation.

Some clues that I got (but wasn't able to find how to do that), were:

- [Best] Find how I can export raw svg files as they are during Typescript compilation without doing that manually, as they are not all in one folder but divided per components areas in the package tree. Doing this, I would tell the other company to add `@svgr/webpack` to its own building process.
- Find how can I tell Typescript to import svg files without specify the extension (currently, removing `.svg` probably makes it fallback to `.ts/tsx` and therefore it cannot find the file with that name). In this way, the `require` would keep requiring the same file name but I could convert SVG to React Components without occurring in problems. But this would also require Typescript to export the file

Otherwise, I should convert all the SVGs in React components and directly use them instead of making them being compiled by `@svgr/webpack`, but I'm not sure this would have some other side-effects.

Any other clues or any way to achieve the ideas I got? Thank you everybody.